# Arch Linux: Reinstall all broken packages after poweroff during system upgrade

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, reinstall, system-failure

There was power failure during system upgrade (`pacman -Suy`). So I have a lot of broken packages. They seems to be fixed on reinstall with force overwriting (e.g `pacman -S systemd-sysvcompat--overwrite "*"`).

So my question is how to apply reinstallation to all broken packages?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming your broken packages are reported as missing files, you can use `Qk` to check packages (from `man pacman`):

> -k, --check
>
> Check that all files owned by the given package(s) are present on the system. If packages are not specified or filter flags are not provided, check all installed packages.
> Specifying this option twice will perform more detailed file checking (including permissions, file sizes, and modification times) for packages that contain the needed mtree file.

So this command should give you the full list of broken packages on your system (the example below is the result on my Arch):

```
$ pacman -Qk 2>/dev/null | grep -v ' 0 missing files' 
at: 45 total files, 1 missing file
audit: 196 total files, 4 missing files
bind: 413 total files, 3 missing files
blueman: 791 total files, 1 missing file
gdm: 501 total files, 6 missing files
gnome-perl: 71 total files, 18 missing files
gnome-vfs-perl: 61 total files, 27 missing files
gnomecanvas-perl: 39 total files, 17 missing files
gvfs: 324 total files, 1 missing file
hplip: 2294 total files, 72 missing files
mariadb: 354 total files, 1 missing file
nfs-utils: 111 total files, 3 missing files
perl-goo-canvas: 59 total files, 18 missing files
perl-gtk2-imageview: 36 total files, 19 missing files
perl-term-shellui: 21 total files, 6 missing files
polkit: 201 total files, 1 missing file
samba: 976 total files, 1 missing file
syslinux: 237 total files, 2 missing files
systemd: 1891 total files, 1 missing file
```

Then, this command will print just the package name:

```
$ pacman -Qk 2>/dev/null | grep -v ' 0 missing files' | cut -d: -f1
at
audit
bind
blueman
gdm
gnome-perl
gnome-vfs-perl
gnomecanvas-perl
gvfs
hplip
mariadb
nfs-utils
perl-goo-canvas
perl-gtk2-imageview
perl-term-shellui
polkit
samba
syslinux
systemd
```

You can just iterate over that list and reinstall each of them:

```
pacman -Qk 2>/dev/null | grep -v ' 0 missing files' | cut -d: -f1 |
    while read -r package; do
        pacman -S "$package" --overwrite "*" --noconfirm
    done
```

Or, if the list isn't too long, you could even do:

```
pacman -S "$(pacman -Qk 2>/dev/null | grep -v ' 0 missing files' | cut -d: -f1)" \
 --overwrite "*" --noconfirm
```

Note that I have *not* tested this and I am taking your word for it that the command will fix your packages. You might also want to run `sudo pacman -Qkk 1>/dev/null 2>&1 | grep checksum` to check for files that have been modified unexpectedly, as suggested by [Tom Yan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/246153/tom-yan) in the comments.

Finally, also be aware that the Arch documentation warns against using the `--overwrite` option (thanks to [Ben Mordecai](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32552/ben-mordecai) for pointing that out in a comment):

> Generally avoid using the --overwrite option with pacman. The --overwrite option takes an argument containing a glob. When used, pacman will bypass file conflict checks for files that match the glob. In a properly maintained system, it should only be used when explicitly recommended by the Arch developers. See the [#Read before upgrading the system](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance#Read_before_upgrading_the_system) section.

Of course, in your case you do not have a properly maintained system because of the power failure during upgrade, so this is might be a good use case for it.

Comment: I think a `pacman -Qkk 1>/dev/null 2>&1 | grep checksum` should at least be run additionally (as root) to see if some files are altered *unexpectedly*.

Comment: Also, is there even any good reason to `2>/dev/null` when `-Qk`?

Comment: @TomYan on my system, there were loads of `No such file or directory` errors, presumably  one for each missing file, so without redirecting stderr there was too much noise. Good point about `checksum`.

Comment: The pacman documentation specifically says not to use the `--overwrite` option unless told to by an Arch developer so be careful those of you who like to paste random commands you find on stack exchange.

Comment: @BenMordecai can you provide a source for that? I'm not doubting you, but I'd like to understand why and what the dangers are.

Comment: @terdon https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance#Avoid_certain_pacman_commands

As of time of my writing this section says `Generally avoid using the --overwrite option with pacman. The --overwrite option takes an argument containing a glob. When used, pacman will bypass file conflict checks for files that match the glob. In a properly maintained system, it should only be used when explicitly recommended by the Arch developers. See the #Read before upgrading the system section.`

Comment: Perfect, thanks @BenMordecai, I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a script that loops through all the packages and reinstalls them.

Just save a list of the packages you've
currently installed to a text file with

```
pacman -Qq > packages.txt
```

and create the script:

```
nano reinstall.sh

#!/bin/bash
for package in $(cat packages.txt)
do
    pacman -S $package --overwrite "*" --noconfirm
done
```

after that you can run it with

```
sudo sh reinstall.sh
```

**Note:** you might have to type `chmod a+x reinstall.sh` to make the script executable first

Comment: [Never use `for i in $(cat file)`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (although it would probably work in this case, it's still bad practice). And you don't need the package list anyway: you can just do `sudo pacman -S "$(pacman -Qq)" --overwrite "*" --noconfirm` or, of that list is too long: `pacman -Qq | while read -r package; do pacman -S "$package" --overwrite "*" --noconfirm; done`. Finally, you have a bash shebang in your script, but then you're running it with `sh script`. That will fail if you have bash-only features. Just do `./reinstall.sh`.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers are useful but neither of them is a complete solution.

Following script helps get rid of errors like this:

```
 ldconfig: File /usr/lib/libsvn_repos-1.so is empty, not checked.
```

script:

```
LANG=en_EN ldconfig 2> err.txt

for file in $(cut -d" " -f3 err.txt)
do
    echo $file
    pacman -S $(pacman -Fq $file) --noconfirm --overwrite "*"
done
```

[pacman -F](https://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html#_file_options_apply_to_em_f_em_a_id_fo_a)

> Query the files database. This operation allows you to look for
> packages owning certain files or display files owned by certain
> packages. Only packages that are part of your sync databases are
> searched. See File Options below.